# My Chrome Extension Settings Page makes my extension corrupted when loading from Chrome Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a very complex Google Extension.

It is working well in Developer Mode, but when deployed in Chrome Store it does not deploy correctly - it results in an corrupted installation.

I've found a quick fix: attempting to install (the icon flickers on the Chrome Toolbar, then disappears,) refresh the Chrome Store page and click the 'Enable Extension' link on the top of the page.

However any attempt to open the setting page (from the pull-down menu, or the link, which I've provided in the Popup window) results in disabling again the extension with the 'corrupted...' message in the Extension page.

I've spent weeks on trying to find the bug.

Not sure what more info to give here, but the extension in Google Web Store is:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wcag-luminosity-contrast/lllpnmpooomecmbmijbmbikaacgfdagi

and the code in GitHub is:

https://github.com/Horiatu/ColorContrast/

Please help!

Comment: [crbug#415323](https://crbug.com/415323) says it might be caused by wrong spelling of paths and indeed this is the case in your extension: the manifest.json references `fonts` but the directory name is `Fonts` (there could other discrepancies, I haven't checked the entire extension). The common practice is to use all lowercase letters. So I suggest doing it for all the directories and files.

Comment: @wOxxOm - thanks. I knew that, but Fonts has escaped me. Also /inc/boostrap has escaped!
I'm in the process of testing it again...

Comment: @wOxxOm - nope! did not work.
Although I've spent a lot of time on paths, I'll give it again attention to it tomorrow.
It is so unfortunately that Google gives no hint on what went wrong... Also that I need 30 minutes on each test... 
Why is Developer Mode so permissive?!

Comment: If you're developing on Windows which isn't case-sensitive in its default file system then apparently unpacked extensions utilize this fact. Just pack the extension and try installing it on a new user profile.

Answer (score 1):

Not only manifest has to use the exact capitations of folders, but folders have to be lowercase!
(I have also removed the /3.1.1/ sub-folder of boostrap, so - not sure if dots are permitted in folder names...)